# redirect inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, routes, navigation

Got a strange bug.
Inside an iframe and trying to redirect using window.location.href.

Instead of redirecting it reloads the original iframe link.
I'm using navigo hash router but it seems unrelated.

Any idea why the page reloads instead of redirecting?

Comment: We've had that, and it can be to do with browser caching/optimization attempts. Try the other properties, location/url etc instead of href--that did it for us.

Comment: Interesting, gave it a go but bug is still here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the `<a>` that started this flow had `href=""` which caused refresh.

Changed it to `<a href="javascript:;">` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Window as the name says references to the main window. I think what you need is `document.location.href` or `document.location.src`. That should it do within iFrame.

Comment: interesting, gave it a go but the bug is still here.

Comment: Not much, just window.location.href, document.location.href or location.url

Comment: Than it is hard to guess what it could be. We have project where we do a lot of redirecting within iFrames. Works quite well.

Comment: Maybe there's an http header that prevents/allows redirect?

Comment: Then it might be browser related, since JS is only client side.